# Removing letters (a-z) from select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a table as like this

```
create table #test
 (id int ,  value varchar(15)  )

 insert into #test 
  values(1,'10')
  ,(2,'12')
  ,(3, '1.3')
  ,(4, 'NO VALUE')

  SELECT * FROM #TEST
```

when i selecting i don't want to see the record 4, i mean any records with the letters like (NO VALUE , NO DATA , (A-Z) ).Can some one help me here please.

Answer (score 3):

To only return rows where value doesn't contain characters in the range `A-Z`

```
SELECT *
FROM   #test
WHERE  value NOT LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess pick whatever performs better for you. You could try something this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #test
WHERE     value != 'NO%'
      AND value NOT LIKE '[a-z]%'
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM #test
WHERE ISNUMERIC(value) = 1
```